# How to change my account's password?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, passwords, shared-folders

I have an account on another server, eg. SOMESERVER, which is in the form of DOMAIN\MyAccount. I can access the shared folder when opening the node SOMESERVER in Network node of the Tree-view of Explorer.

I don't know how to change my current password to access the folder.

Please help.

Comment: Can you be more specific, do you want to change the password on your machine or on the folder? Also is your machine on a domain or not?

Comment: @Diago:

1. I want to change the password when accessing *node SOMESERVER in Network*

Comment: I understand that part. The question is, are you on a domain. IF you are, changing your local password will work, however if your not, the password needs to be changed on the server. You need to be much more specific before you will get to the correct solution.

Comment: @Diago: 2. I don't know how to know whether I'm on a domain or not. Please show me how to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do the belowings:

1. Ctrl - Alt - Del
2. Change password...
3. Enter the information required there
4. Done

Cheers!

Comment: I disagree. This is to change the password for the local machine account, but will only work if the machine is on a domain etc.

Comment: @Diago: Using the method in this answer changes the user password for the user that's currently logged on. If you're logged on with a local user account it will change the local user account password, if you're logged on with a domain user account it will change the domain user account password.

Comment: @joe Correct, you gave the long explanation, *however* my concern is that the OP hasn't supplied enough information to confirm that the above solution will work for his requirement. If he is not on a domain, changing is local password might break more then what it fixes. *I concur that I may be a bit pedantic about this, but I have seen to many mistakes in the past not to raise the point*